# Unable to render observableArray

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, knockout.js

I have this code that I am expecting to render the menus which is queried from REST:

```
        var PageViewModel = function() {
            var self = this;
//                  self.menus = [
//                      { name: 'Foor', slug: 'foo'},
//                      { name: 'Bar', slug: 'bar'},
//                      { name: 'Fam', slug: 'fam' }
//                  ];
            self.menus = ko.observableArray();
            var result = query.find({
                success: function(results) {
                    console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " menus.");
                    var menus = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var object = results[i];
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
                        menus.push(object);
                    }
                    self.menus(menus);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });
            console.log('Menus = ' + JSON.stringify(self.menus));
            this.transitionTo = function(slug) {
                window.location.href = slug + ".html";
            }
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="uk-text-center" data-bind="foreach: menus()">
    <li class="">
        <button class="button button-white uk-margin-bottom"><span data-bind="text: name">Foo</span></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that the menus rendered the list but names are empty. However if I just let the code use the static array, it works fine. With this I tried to debug with Chrome and from what I see something might be missing:

[image]

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Could you please expose a bit more of the HTML? And also, is there anything in the console output? You might need to use `foreach:menus()` but need more details thanks

Comment: I added the HTML code. Also if I change the code to `foreach:menus()` the error is `Message: menus is not a function`

Comment: You have `Parse.Object`s in your `results` array which don't have properties exposed, so you need to convert them to JSON before passing to Knockout `menus.push(object.toJSON());`

Comment: Where is you `applyBindings` code? @xybrek

Comment: Just below the ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way.

Refer [foreach-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) for more info on how to use.

Hope this solves your problem. Made changes in the code.

```js
var PageViewModel = function() 
 {
            var self = this;
   
            self.menus = ko.observableArray([]);
            var result = query.find(
              {
                success: function(results) 
                {
                    console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " menus.");
                    var menus = [];
                    
                    for (var i in results)
                    {
                        var object = results[i];
                        
                        menus.push(object.toJSON());
                    }
                    self.menus(menus);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });
            
            this.transitionTo = function(slug) {
                window.location.href = slug + ".html";
            }
        }

ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="uk-text-center" data-bind="foreach: menus">
    <li class="">
        <button class="button button-white uk-margin-bottom"><span data-bind="text: name">Foo</span></button>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Good - but for performance, push instead to the local `menus` array, and then use `self.menus(menus)`. That way you are updating the observable once per data item, and triggering the refresh each time.

Comment: That way I never used. I used to do the way I have written in the code. Then there wont be any difference between the code in question and answer, except the change in HTML code.

Comment: ps - if the data is already an array, the `length` test and the `for` can be dropped and just go `self.menus(results)`

Comment: @titi23 thanks it works now, the toJSON() was the missing code

Comment: @xybrek glad it helped.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The objects in your menus array in your inspector don't have a name property for you to bind. Try `className`, or if you have control over the data you're getting, use different names like `name` and `slug` or whatever you want.